# How to make span and image on the same line?

Tags: html, css, layout, line-breaks

I have a span element with text in it followed by an image that I want on the same line, but for some reason, it isn't.

I have tried using `display: inline-block` and `whitespace: nowrap` but none of them seem to work too.

It currently looks like this, I added red borders so that it is kind of clear.

[image]

My current HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="heading2" style="border: red solid 5px;">
    <div>
        <span style="border: red solid 5px;" id="headings2_span">Entrada</span>
    </div><div>
        <img src="../assets/thumbnails/responsive_menu_icon-512.png" alt="Menu" id="headings2_menu" style="border: red solid 5px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And it's corresponding CSS is as follows:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading2{
    float: right;
}

#headings2_span{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#headings2_menu{
    width: 7%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use flex.

```css
 .heading2{
        float: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="heading2" style="border: red solid 5px;">
    <div>
        <span style="border: red solid 5px;" id="headings2_span">Entrada</span>
    </div><div>
    <img src="align-left.png" alt="Menu" id="headings2_menu" style="border: red solid 5px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using bootstrap 4, for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span style="border: red solid 5px;" id="headings2_span">Entrada</span>
        <img src="../assets/thumbnails/responsive_menu_icon-512.png" alt="Menu" id="headings2_menu" style="border: red solid 5px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For additional information, I suggest that you consult these websites:
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/)
[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: It works in bringing the span and the image in the same line but now I can't float it to the right of the screen. Do you know why?

Comment: Like @kd patel said below, you should use `display: flex`

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want keep space between them. use justify-content property. I would suggest learn flex. I have hardly used float properties since i started learning flex.

```css
.heading2{
        float: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<div class="heading2" style="border: red solid 5px;">
    <div>
        <span style="border: red solid 5px;" id="headings2_span">Entrada</span>
    </div><div>
    <img src="align-left.png" alt="Menu" id="headings2_menu" style="border: red solid 5px;">
</div>
```